# How to grant privileges to one user to access other users in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

There are 3 schemas: DEMO1, DEMO2, DEMO3
I want to grant DEMO1 permissions to perform all the operations on DEMO2 and not DEMO3.

ALL Operations means: Select, Update, Insert, Delete

How can I grant the privileges for that in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: What do you mean by *all*? For example, for `DROP`: *The table must be in your own schema or you must have the DROP **ANY** TABLE **system privilege**.*

Comment: I want to give all privileges to DEMO1 for DEMO2 only. And not for DEMO3. Sorry for editing the question again. @astentx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do that. With many DDL privileges - as astentx pointed out - you either are constrained to what you own, or you can affect *ANY* table in the system, not just one other user. There's no middle ground unless you're also working with add-on enterprise products like Database Vault. If you're talking about DML (insert, update, delete of data), then grant the specific table privileges to a role and grant the role to DEMO1.

```
create role demo2_dml;
grant insert, update, delete on demo2.table_a to demo2_dml;
grant insert, update, delete on demo2.table_b to demo2_dml;
...
grant role demo2_dml to demo1;
alter user demo1 default role all;
```

Alternatively, if you must have DDL privileges as well, you could give DEMO1 *proxy* privileges to become DEMO2 and assume all of its privileges on its objects.

```
alter user demo2 grant connect through demo1;
```

Then connect using `demo1[demo2]` as the username, with demo1's password:

```
connect demo1[demo2]/demo1password@database_service
```

demo1 then becomes demo2 (without needing to know demo2's password) and can do anything demo2 would be able to do. demo1 would not have access to its *own* objects while doing this, however.